# Same operations taking different time

Tags: c++, assembly

I am in the process of optimizing my code for my n-body simulator, and when profiling my code, have seen this:

[image]

These two lines,

---

```
float diffX = (pNode->CenterOfMassx - pBody->posX);
float diffY = (pNode->CenterOfMassy - pBody->posY);
```

Where `pNode` is a pointer to a object of type `Node` that I have defined, and contains (with other things) 2 floats, `CenterOfMassx` and `CenterOfMassy`

Where `pBody` is a pointer to a object of type `Body` that I have defined, and contains (with other things) 2 floats, `posX` and `posY`.

---

*Should* take the same amount of time, but do not. In fact the first line accounts for 0.46% of function samples, but the second accounts for 5.20%.

Now I can see the second line has 3 instructions, and the first only has one.

My question is why do these *seemingly* do the same thing but in practice to different things?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As previously stated, profiler is listing only one assembly instruction with the first line, but three with the second line. However, because the optimizer can move code around a lot, this isn't very meaningful. It looks like the code is optimized to load all of the values into registers first, and then perform the subtractions. So it performs an action from the first line, then an action from the second line (the loads), followed by an action from the first line and an action from the second line (the subtractions). Since this is difficult to represent, it just does a best approximation of which line corresponds to which assembly code when displaying the disassembly inline with the code.

Take note that the first load is executed and may still be in the CPU pipeline when the next load instruction is executing. The second load has no dependence on the registers used in the first load. However, the first subtraction does. This instruction requires the previous load instruction to be far enough in the pipeline that the result can be used as one of the operands of the subtraction. This will likely cause a stall in the CPU while the pipeline lets the load finish.

All of this really reinforces the concept of memory optimizations being more important on modern CPUs than CPU optimizations. If, for example, you had loaded the required values into registers 15 instructions earlier, the subtractions might have occurred much quicker.

Generally the best thing you can do for optimizations is to keep the cache fresh with the memory you are going to using, and making sure it gets updated as soon as possible, and not right before the memory is needed. Beyond that, optimizations are *complicated*.

Of course, all of this is further complicated by modern CPUs that might look ahead 40-60 instructions for [out of order execution.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution)

To optimize this further, you might consider using a library that does vector and matrix operations in an optimized manner. Using one of these libraries, it might be possible to use two vector instructions instead of 4 scalar instructions.

Answer (score 3):

According to the expanded assembly, the instructions are reordered to load `pNodes`'s data members before performing subtraction with `pBody`'s data members. The purpose may be to take advantage of memory caching.

Thus, the execution order is not the same as C code anymore. Comparing 1 movss which is accounted for the 1st C statement with 1 movss + 2 subss which are accounted for the 2nd C statement is unfair.

Comment: So, why do the lines of code become different assembly instructions, and is there any way to speed up the second line to be as fast as the first?

Comment: Each line becomes the same two asm instructions, but they're reordered.  One source line gets one insn and the other gets 3, because otherwise the asm instructions would have to be shown out of order.  It's not to take advantage of caching, BTW.  It's to better hide the latency of the load.

Comment: If `pNode` is far away from `pBody`, doesn't it take advantage of caching by loading `*pNode` before `*pBody` compared to interleaving?

Answer (score 1):

Performance counters aren't cycle-accurate.  Sometimes the wrong instruction gets blamed.  But in this case, it's probably pointing the finger at the instruction that was producing the result everything else was waiting for.

So probably it ran out of things it could do while waiting for the result of the memory access and FP sub.  If cache misses are happening, look for ways to structure your code for better memory locality, or at least for memory access to happen in-order.  Hardware prefetchers can detect sequential access patterns up to some limit of stride length.

Also, you compiler could have vectorized this.  It loads two scalars from sequential addresses, then subtracts two scalars from sequential addresses.  It would be faster to

```
movq xmm0, [esi+30h]   # or movlps, but that wouldn't break the dep
movq xmm1, [edi]       # on the old value of xmm0 / xmm1
subps xmm0, xmm1
```

That leaves `diffX` and `diffY` in element 0 and 1 of `xmm0`, rather than 2 different regs, so the benefit depends on the surrounding code.